# Using multiple dataSources in Grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am using `Grails 2.4.4`. I am trying to configure multiple DataSources by following [these Grails docs](https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.4.4/guide/conf.html#multipleDatasources).

Based on documentation I have added multiple `dataSources` in `DataSource.groovy`. Docs say that in domain classes I can specify `dataSource` by using following statement.

```
static mapping = {
    datasource 'datasource_name'
}
```

Similarly in service class `dataSource` to be used can be specified as,

```
static datasource = 'datasource_name'
```

But above guidelines assume that domain and service classes are `*.groovy` classes. My domain and service classes are `*.java` classes.
The syntax in above code samples will give compilation errors in `java` code.

I would like to know how can I apply these instructions to `*.java` domain and service class.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use Java for domain classes. You must use Groovy.